# Simplify with function composition

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to write an expression of the form $a/\sqrt{b c}$ as $a/d$ where $d = \sqrt{bc}$. My hope was to use a similar strategy as when the square root is omitted:

```
Simplify[a/(b c), d == b c]
```

which yields `a/d`.

However,

```
Simplify[a/Sqrt[(b c)], d == Sqrt[b c], Assumptions -> {b > 0, c > 0}]
```

yields `a/Sqrt[b c]`. As shown, I tried specifying that b, c are positive, but this makes no difference. I have also tried `FullSimplify`.

I find the same behavior with `Simplify[a/(b c), d == 1/(b c)]` and `Simplify[Exp[a]/(b c), d == Exp[a]]`, so there is clearly something going wrong when there is a composition, or when the right hand side of "==" is something other than `Plus[blark, blah]` or `Times[blark, blah]`.

Does anyone see what I am missing here?

EDIT:

I should clarify, the use-cases I have are more complicated than the simple example above. As pointed out, the simple cases can be handled by `TransformationFunctions`. It is not clear this approach works for more complex expressions, such as

```
Simplify[Exp[a] (g + h)/Sqrt[(b c)], d == Exp[a] (g + h)/Sqrt[(b c)]]
```

which is more of interest.

Comment: maybe something like `Replace[HoldForm[a/Sqrt[b c]], HoldPattern[Sqrt[b c]] -> d, All]`?

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following instead:

```
Simplify[a/Sqrt[b c], d^2==b c && d>0]
```

> a/d

Your other examples can be handled by making use of [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions), although I don't know how robust it would be for more complicated examples:

```
Simplify[
    a/(b c),
    TransformationFunctions->{ReplaceAll[b -> 1/(c d)], Automatic}
]
```

> a d

```
Simplify[
    Exp[a]/(b c),
    TransformationFunctions->{ReplaceAll[a -> Log[d]],Automatic}
]
```

> d/(b c)

Comment: Thanks @Carl Woll and also @Nasser. This looks promising. What about expressions like `Simplify[Exp[a]/Sqrt[(b c)], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {ReplaceAll[a -> Log[(b c) d^2]/2], 
   Automatic}]`? This strategy does not appear to work...

Answer (score 3):

May be as a workaround

```
Simplify[a/Sqrt[b c], d^2 == (b c), Assumptions -> d > 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]